# Clockify API stop running stopwatch

Tags: rest, clockify

is there a simple way to stop a running stopwatch for a time entry?
I could probably edit the end time via updating the specific entry but I would have to get the Id, store it and so on...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you only need to know the ID of the workspace. Use the following endpoint:

```
PUT /workspaces/{workspaceId}/timeEntries/endStarted
```

with the following body:

```
{ end: "2018-10-16T10:54:39.883Z" }
```

This should be documented in the next revision of API docs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution. Works like a charm now!